# Modulo / Modulus - how to use them?

Tags: mathematics

In mathematics there is the concept of modulo **roughly** the remainer of an integer division, e.g. mod(9,2) gives 1, since taking as many 2 out of 9 as possible, 1 is left.

However, I also come across the term modulus, is there a difference? (there is also the related operation remainer, which deal with negative values differently, but that is not it).

Comment: Have you tried looking them up online or in a dictionary?

Comment: Yes, I did research quite a bit, I could not find an answer.

Comment: Including in your question what you found in dictionaries is important, since otherwise your question is likely to be downvoted or closed.

Comment: I think the more common ***modulus*** is a noun, but ***modulo*** is probably an adjective. Not that it really matters if people use them differently. The underlying meaning is so "precise" that there's little scope for misunderstanding - there's just scope for pedants to whinge about syntactically incorrect text. (I'd just go for abbreviated ***mod*** to sidestep the pedants! :)

Comment: The mod operator returns the smallest positive residue of some dividend with respect to some modulus. The integer quotient is the number of times a divisor divides the dividend. But the modulus is a different concept to a divisor because the mod operation is used to create equivalence classes.

Answer (score 1):

"modulus" is to the "modulo" function as "divisor" is to the "division" function. So in your example of `mod(9, 2)`, the modulus is `2`.

The functional form `mod(9, 2)` is more commonly used in computer programming, not math. In mathematics, "modulo" is usually used as a modifier, typically

> 9 ≡ 1 mod 2

which is read as

> 9 is equivalent to 1 modulo 2

Answer (score 1):

Modulus has, perversely, various totally distinct meanings even in the maths domain. Here are two:

> [(A)] *modulus* [noun] 1. [MATHEMATICS]
>
> - another term for absolute value.

[[Oxford Languages; courtesy of Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=modulus+meaning&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&oq=modulus+me&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUqBwgAEAAYgAQyBwgAEAAYgAQyBggBEEUYOTIHCAIQABiABDIHCAMQABiABDIHCAQQABiABDIHCAUQABiABDIHCAYQABiABDIHCAcQABiABDINCAgQLhivARjHARiABDIHCAkQABiABKgCALACAA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)]

It is coded for by enclosing a number in square brackets.

Hence [3] = 3 and [-3] = 3; [] =  and [-] = . In numerical algebra, [**x**] = -x rather than x if x is itself negative (say -14·2): here, the absolute value is correspondingly [-14·2] = 14·2, ie -x.

.....................

> *modulus* 4.  [mathematics]
>
> - an integer that can be divided exactly into the difference between two other integers
>
> *7 is a modulus of 25 and 11* [(as are 2 and 14)]

[[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/modulus)]

In modular arithmetic, two integers leaving the same remainder on division in turn by the same number (thus, for example, 22 and 107 when divided by 5) are said to be congruent modulo that number.

This is usually written

22  ≡ 107 mod 5.

Here, obviously the most basic member is 2, though there are infinite members of the set (including -3, -8 ...): an arithmetic progression, obviously with common difference 5. The set is known as 'residue class 2 modulo 5'.